# Could this be done any easier? Java beginner question

Tags: java, android

I need to create a series of objects, and it just looks plain ugly right now:

```
CheckBox checkOne = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkOne);
CheckBox checkTwo = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkTwo;
CheckBox checkThree = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkThree);
CheckBox checkFour = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkFour);
CheckBox checkFive = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkFive);
```

I'm on an intermediate level when it comes to Java, so what I wanted to do was to do a for loop and then use variable variables. Alas, Java does not support this. Is there any, less recursive, way to do this?

Comment: I'm in two minds whether to remove the 'java' tag from this question as the issue you're having is Android specific and not to do with Java. @Don Roby's code in his answer so far is the closest to what you want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the lookup keys are ints, you can do it like this:

```
CheckBox[] boxes = new CheckBox[5];
int[] ids = new int[]{R.id.checkOne, R.id.checkTwo, R.id.checkThree, 
                      R.id.checkFour, R.id.checkFive};

for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
   boxes[i] = (CheckBox) findViewById(ids[i])
}
```

If the keys are something else, you'll of course need to change the type of the `ids` array.

And if you have control over how these keys are held in the `R` class, you might better just make them an array there.

You might also be better off using Lists instead of arrays.

Comment: "And if you have control over how these keys are held in the R class" - the `R` class in Android is auto-generated at build time. Your code example is pretty much what the OP needs to do however. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
CheckBox[] boxes = new CheckBox[]{(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkOne), 
                    (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkTwo), ...};
```

You can initialize arrays like this or an int array and iterate a `for` loop over this array.

Comment: Thanks for a solution, but this looks just as ugly. How would the 'for' loop look then?

Comment: I don't know, depends on your usage. This won't look uglier than having parameters named checkOne, checkTwo.. Let's say you want to hide all checkboxes, then `for(CheckBox c : boxes){c.setVisibility(false);} ` there you go an usage instead of `checkOne.setVisiblity(false); checkTwo.setVisiblity(false); ...`

Answer (score 1):

If checkOne, checkTwo etc. are fields on R.id, then the only way to iterate over them is by using reflection. This isn't exactly elegant, but this is the way you would have to handle this in java.

```
    List<CheckBox> boxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
    for(Field f : R.id.getClass().getFields()) {
        if(f.getName().startsWith("check")) {
            boxes.add((CheckBox) findViewById(f.get(R.id)));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to get the check boxes by id-name string variables, then name the checkboxes `checkbox1`, `checkbox2` etc. and access them this way:

```
String view_name = "";
CheckBox[] boxes = new CheckBox[5];
Integer x=0, y;
for (x=0;x<5;x++){
    y=x+1;
    view_name = "checkbox"+ y.toString();
    boxes[x] = (CheckBox) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(view_name,"id", getPackageName()));
}
```